# Disabling vim's startup message (vimdiff, vim -o -O ones)

Tags: vim, message, startup

When using opening multiple files with split windows from the command line, vim likes to state what the file names are, the line count, and the character count, for each file. Then the user is prompted to press enter to continue on to the good stuff.

Is there an setting or switch to disable this? I'm using this for diffing with TortoiseSVN and the message is killing my productivity when all I want is a quick glance at the changes.

Comment: I've just tried this on vim on two machines, but I'm not getting the same behaviour.
When I vimdiff it tells me that there are 2 files to edit (at the command prompt) for a second before launching vim. Could it be one of your plugins? Which version of vim are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to play with 'shortmess' vim option.

```
:help shortmess
```

Either set it in your .vimrc

```
set shortmess=at
```

or during the vim run

```
vim --cmd 'set shortmess=at'
```

Comment: As a reference point: my shortmess is set to "filnxtToO" sans quotes.  I haven't modified it at all so I expect this is the default for many common installs.

Comment: yeap, this is default according to help.

Comment: After having a quick read through the help, I conclude that these are not the messages I have in mind. These seem to be messages relevant to when vim has loaded already. Andy below has the message that I was inquiring about. My shm=atl which was default.

Comment: ipwnponies: I've just set my shm=atl in my vimrc and tried to diff some files and I'm getting the same sort of behavior you described in your original post. Setting my shm=filnxtToO (which was default for my system) does get rid of the prompt again. Are you sure that the answer isn't applicable?

Comment: Andy is right, it's the o or O options that remove the message. I thought I knew the insides and out of it all. shm was set to atl. =(

What's the diffrernence between o and O? I can't grasp what they do in the first place, let alone their differences.

Comment: It looks like they're flags for the cases where vim wants to display more than one bit of information at once, e.g. to inform you of successful writing of previous changes to a file, and straight after the word and character counts for the new file being opened.

Comment: It doesnt work. It still show the messege like `Highlight current word: ON`

Answer (score 7):

Mykola Golubyev's answer ist good, but you probably want to use `+=` instead of `=` in order to keep the flags that are already present.

```
set shortmess+=at
```

Otherwise it might have unwanted side effects like those mentioned in the above comments.