# gVim startup message & info suppression

Tags: session, vim, startup

I got a partial answer to my problem before, and want to solve this problem fully now. The final line of my /Program Files/GNU/vim/_vimrc  is

```
source /homedir/vimsession_file
```

The filenames that i edit do not change, only their content changes. But, once in a while, i would create a new session file before i exit vim, using

```
:mks!  /homedir/vimsession_file
```

Everytime i start gVim, i get a message box listing all the files (which I load into the multiple tabs that i have) with a Line number and Character count listed. More detail of this can be found in my [orignal post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448185/gvim-windows-message-popup-box-with-ok-button).

Currently, i am **not using** the solution proposed in the link given above. The solution i got there was to replace the final line of */Program Files/GNU/vim/_vimrc* with the following line:

```
autocmd VimEnter * source /homedir/vimsession_file
```

The reason I stopped using the above solution is because my buffers were all getting wiped out (as described in the original post link). So, i was forced to rebuild my buffers every once in a while, when i would restart gVim.

I did search and read in order to solve this on my own. But the closest solution that i saw was [here in stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645568/disabling-vims-startup-message-vimdiff-vim-o-o-ones) But that solution did not work for me either, despite playing with the **shortmess** variable as suggested there.  How can i stop this annoying message box that pops up with OK button, before the start of gVim ?  I want to suppress the message box, because the only info i get from it are the line and character count for each file.  (NOTE: I looked into the */homedir/vimsession_file* and it is about 3500 lines long. I noticed that the file names occur with *badd followed by the edit command.*  For example, i have line 96 and line 164 as below:

```
Line 96 :   badd +16 \Program\ Files\GNU\vim\_vimrc
........
Line 164:   edit \Program\ Files\GNU\vim\_vimrc
```

This pattern repeats for all the other files that get loaded into multiple windows/tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to post the answer here because there seem to be very few VIM experts who regularly look at stackoverflow. I didn't have the patience to wait many days expecting an answer. I found the answer to my own question, after reading the help file in vim called "starting.txt" which explains the startup/init process of vim and the different  initialization files used. The following steps removed the annoying pop-up message box for me, and also made my VIM process start much faster than before due to simplification.

1. According to what is suggested in *starting.txt* help file, I separated my numerous tabs/windows/files  into  different sessions. I recommend reading through this help file (atleast browsing it), if you are a regular user of VIM.
2. Previously i was lumping numerous files (from different projects) into one single vim session. This is messy and is not the recommended way to use a VIM session file. Before the creation of different session files (for different projects), i first saved my old *vim session* file so that i can reuse it, during the creation of different session files. You will understand the process clearly if you look at the help file.
3. I cleaned up my startup procedure further by setting up a new viminfo file, by adding the "-i" parameter to vim.exe (icon) for starting. This was pointed to a new directory and hence gave a fresh start.
4. The main init files used by vim are *viminfo*, *vimrc* and *session file*. Each is meant for a different purpose. My problem was caused by `source /homedir/vimsession_file` as the final line of in my *vimrc*. So, I removed that line, and instead issue that command manually now, after vim starts up (with an empty window). I can **source** different *vimsession_files*, in order to load different files (which belong together). On my machine this command takes about 1 second, to load many tabs/windows/files, which belong to a single project/sub-project.
5. As pointed in the *original post* URL given in my question,  there maybe another way to resolve this by creating and looking at the *vimlog* file. But i didn't want to bother with that tedious process. The way i am setup now makes more sense to me, because I have various *subprojects* which properly belong in different sessions of VIM.